# jquery animate turns out tricky

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i'm trying to solve a task which seems easy but doesn't work as it should.
i'm having 2 links, when clicking them they show a corresponding div.

what i wanna do is:

when clicking link #1: show div #1, when clicking link #2: show div#2.

i want to let the div fade in and slide in at the same time, meaning the divs should crossfade over each other.

my current code for animating the div is:

```
        div.animate({
            "height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle"
        }, "slow");
```

the problem is - when quickly clicking between both links, the animation would go mad and keep animating several times ..
any ideas how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: more code example please

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.stop(true, true)`

```
div.stop(true, true).animate({
    "height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle"
}, "slow");
```